# Checking at least one checkbox within groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I've got a set of checkboxes in labels, like so

```
<div class="constraints">
<label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
    </label>
    .
    .
    .
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
    </label>
</label>
.
.
.
<label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
    </label>
    .
    .
    .
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
    </label>
</label>
</div>
```

Within each group of labels (`.constraints > label`) at least one checkbox must be checked. To ensure this, I wrote this jQuery code, which should simply tick off the first box in the group if all of them are unchecked.

```
$('form .constraints input').on('change', function() {
    var checks = $(this).closest('.constraints > label').find('input') ;

    var atleastone = false ;

    checks.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            atleastone = true ;
        }
    }) ;

    if (!atleastone) {
        checks.first().attr('checked', true) ;
    }
}) ;
```

Which works exactly once. The first time I check or uncheck *any* of the boxes, the script works, but any subsequent calls result in nothing.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change every place you have

```
.attr('checked')
.attr('checked', true)
```

to

```
.prop('checked')
.prop('checked', true)
```

To see why, you can check [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

You could shorten your code a lot by doing

```
$('form .constraints input').on('change', function() {
  var checks = $(this).closest('.constraints > label').find('input');
  var checked = checks.filter(':checked').length == 0;
  if (checked) checks.first().prop('checked', checked);
});
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple and silly I was missing. Thanks